# Moving internal pointer ahead with mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which looks something like the following (first row is columns):

```
|section | col1 | col2 |
|----------------------|
|bananas | val  | val2 |
|----------------------|
|peaches | val  | val2 |
```

With some code to check if a section value matches up with one of the values in an array:

```
$sectionscope = Array('bananas', 'apples');

$sections = mysql_query("SELECT section FROM table WHERE col1=val AND col2=val2");

if (mysql_num_rows($sections)) {

    $i = 0;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sections)) {

        if (in_array($row[$i], $sectionscope)) {

            $section = $sectionscope[array_search($row[$i], $sectionscope)];

            $section_is_valid = 1;

        }

        $i++;

    }

}
```

If I echo the output from the while loop using echo $row[$i], it gives me: `bananas`

Doing the select from PHPmyadmin works fine

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks,

SystemError

Comment: Why don't you query for the sections you want in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you incrementing `$i` in the while loop. Your query will return two rows and when you loop through the results, you can access the `section` value using `$row[0]` each time.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sections)) {
echo $row[0];    
}
```

This will print `bananas` and `peaches`.

In your code, when you enter the while loop second time, you are trying to retrieve `section` value using `$row[1]` (since your `$i` has incremented to 1), which will be null since your query result only contains one column.

Comment: Woops, classic logical mistake. I keep thinking about the rows as iterating across the index numbers when those are fields not rows. Thanks